# why view.center is assignable but view.frame.origin or view.frame.size are not

Tags: ios

[sorry for my weak english]

question as stated in the title:

why view.center is assignable but view.frame.origin 
or view.frame.size are not :-!

it is not undesterable by me

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new one and then assign it.

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(1, 2, 3, 4);

// or
CGRect frame = view.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointMake(1, 2);
view.frame = frame;

// etc...
view.frame = (CGRect){1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Comment: Tnx much - (CGRect){1, 2, 3, 4}; is very helpful, but still we do not know, why i can assign rect to frame but not point to origin :-!

Comment: In my example I assign `origin` on the frame. You can also assign `point` to it. Not sure what you mean with "assign rect to frame" though.